# Can't serve php custom error files from a parent folder in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I have the following directory scheme

```
/srv/www/htdocs/www/
```

where www is the public directory root, and htdocs contains files outside the public access. This is the nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;

    root   /srv/www/htdocs/www;

    location / {
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page 401 @errorPage;
    error_page 403 @errorPage;
    error_page 404 @errorPage;
    location @errorPage {
        root /srv/www/htdocs;
        rewrite ^ error.php?error=$status last;
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to serve the error.php page when 401,403 and 404 triggers, but still I'm getting the default Nginx 404 page, even when I programmatically trigger 403 or 401.

Am I doing something wrong in the named location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing `root` in `@errorPage` is pointless. The location is a stepping stone to `error.php` which ends up back in the `location ~ \.php$` with a root value of `/srv/www/htdocs/www`.

The simplest solution is to move `error.php` into the `www` directory.

---

If you want to keep `error.php` out of the `www` directory, you will need to replicate much of the `location ~ \.php$` block within the `location @errorPage` block.

For example:

```
location @errorPage {
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/htdocs/error.php;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING error=$status;
}
```

Place the `fastcgi_param` statements **after** the `include`, otherwise the latter will override the new values.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked!!!

By the way I want to exclude the error page outside the public access, that's why I moved the file is the parent folder.